# Not able to access form elements when there page is called with a querystring

Tags: javascript

I have a number of webpages on which I have the following piece of Javascript

```
 var inputs = $("body :input");
 for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
 {
  thisObj =inputs[i];// test if the class 'roll' exists
  if (thisObj.getAttribute('type') == 'text')
  {
   params+=thisObj.id + "="+thisObj.value+"&";
  }
 }
```

If the page it is called from does not have any querystring elements tagged on to the URL (i.e. localhost/default.aspx ) it works fine and params is populated.

If however it is called from a page containing a querystring element in the url (i.e. localhost/default.aspx?ref=42) inputs is returned as an empty array and params is blank.

I know that I have probably missed something very obvious but for the life of my I cannot work out what the cause is.

Edit:

To be clearer if I simplify the code to:-

```
var par=''; 
var inputs = $("body :input"); 
par ="c="+inputs.length;
```

I get c=9 if the url does not have a GET parameter and an empty string if the url has a GET parameter

Comment: I don't see how the above code could be affected by a GET parameter. Does your ASP page behave differently when the parameter is set? Does the form exist in the HTML source code then?

Comment: The GET parameter does not do anything. I initially added it to ensure that the page was really refreshed when debugging the javascript code.  This resulted in the error above. Removing the GET parameters and refreshing the page resulted in the script running fine so the problem is reproducible.

Comment: Slightly off subject, but did you know you can also do the following: $("body :input[type='text']")

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me. Have you tried debugging the code? I like chrome for stepping through code

Answer (score 0):

The code appears to be preparing a querystring (the variable `params`) by collecting data from various input fields on a page, most likely for a subsequent redirect to a dynamically generated URL containing the form data in the form of GET parameters. Note that the jQuery selector `"body :input"` effectively selects all elements within the entire page that can reasonably be used for user input (input, textarea, select and button, to be precise).

Thus, the code is likely intended to be used on the page where where the query string that you refer to is assebled, and not the one on which the parameters are read and put into use.

Comment: But the jQuery selector is failing to return any values when a querystring exists. If I change the code to par='';
var inputs = $("body :input");
par+="c="+inputs.length+"&"; I get c=9 if the url does not have a GET parameter and an empty string if the url has a GET parameter

Comment: Your JS does look ok to me (although it appears copy/pasted from a jQuery context, judging by the variable names). I think that we would need to see the full document (including server side code) to be able to help here.